# Accessing values of list using for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

```py
name_input = 'abc'
password_input = 123

names = ['abc', 'root']
passwords = [123, 456]

for name, password in names, passwords:
    if name == name_input and password == password_input:
        print('Valid')
    else:
        print('Invalid')
```

Output:

```
Invalid 
Invalid
```

Expected output:

```
Valid 
Invalid
```

What's the problem with this code?

Comment: you need `zip(names, passwords)`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by enke, you need [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
name_input = 'abc'
password_input = 123

names = ['abc', 'root']
passwords = [123, 456]

for name, password in zip(names, passwords):
    if all({name == name_input, password == password_input}):
        print('Valid')
    else:
        print('Invalid')
```

The code above outputs:

```
Valid
Invalid
```

As you expected.

Another option is to have a list or a dictionary of name and password pairs:

```py
name_input = 'abc'
password_input = 123

names_and_passwords = [
    ('abc', 123),
    ('root', 456)
]

for name, password in names_and_passwords:
    if all({name == name_input, password == password_input}):
        print('Valid')
    else:
        print('Invalid')
```

```py
name_input = 'abc'
password_input = 123

names_and_passwords = {
    'abc': 123,
    'root': 456
}

for name, password in names_and_passwords.items():
    if all({name == name_input, password == password_input}):
        print('Valid')
    else:
        print('Invalid')
```

Which gives you the same result.

Comment: Is there any reason you used *set* instead of a *tuple* inside `all()` ?

Comment: I have used a [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set) because it is more efficient, IMHO. I think it is better because it will remove all duplicated values.

Comment: Yes I know but I asked, why did you prefer a set over a tuple as your iterable ?

Comment: *set* is more efficient when you are doing a membership testing, **not always**. sets are bigger than tuples in memory. Also creation of sets takes longer than a tuple since the items inside of it are needed to be hashed first. In your case, sets are not helping you.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary, thanks for the explanation. Do you think it is a less efficient option when used in `all()`?

Comment: Actually I asked this out of curiosity, I wanted to know if you had any specific reason to so. They are just 2 values that we're dealing with so either way, it doesn't matter really. I upvoted you

Comment: No worries. It is always good to learn new stuff and discussing it here is always a good way to achieve that. :-) Thanks for the upvote.